# How to hide Windows 7 updates in batch, based on KB number?

Tags: batch-processing, windows-update

Hy,
I'm interested to find a way (maybe vbs script?) to hide several (more than 10, anyway) windows 7 updates, so they never get installed.
I think the best way would be if I could parse a .txt file where I have each KB number listed (each on new line). But of course, if it makes the code simpler, an array hardcoded inside the script would work as well. The only requirement would be to go by KB number and not by description.

The problem is that I have no idea how I should do this and therefore I am asking help from you guys.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely do this with a VBS script. Similar questions have already been answered on some of the other StackExchange sites (see [How to disable the “Get Windows 10” icon shown in the notification area (tray)?](https://superuser.com/a/922921/243707) and also [Block specific Windows update hotfix](https://serverfault.com/a/341318/184613))

The parts that are relevant to your question are copied below. The original questions are worth reading, and they have additional notes that might also be helpful.

These were written specifically to deal with the GWX updates, but you can use any KB number with them.

**"BlockWindows10.bat"**:

```
ECHO OFF
REM --- remember to invoke from ELEVATED command prompt!
REM --- or start the batch with context menu "run as admin".
SETLOCAL

REM --- (as of 2015-09-07):
REM  KB3035583 - GWX Update installs Get Windows 10 app in Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 SP1
REM  KB3021917 - Update to Windows 7 SP1 for performance improvements
REM  KB3012973 - Upgrade to Windows 10 Pro

REM --- no longer blocking:
REM  KB2952664 - Compatibility update for upgrading Windows 7
REM  KB2976978 - Compatibility update for Windows 8.1 and Windows 8
REM  KB3022345 - Telemetry [Replaced by KB3068708]
REM  KB3068708 - Update for customer experience and diagnostic telemetry

REM --- uninstall updates
echo uninstalling updates ...
start "title" /b /wait wusa.exe /kb:3021917 /uninstall /quiet /norestart
echo  - next
start "title" /b /wait wusa.exe /kb:3035583 /uninstall /quiet /norestart
echo  - done.
timeout 10

REM --- hide updates
echo hiding updates ...
start "title" /b /wait cscript.exe "%~dp0HideWindowsUpdates.vbs" 3021917 3035583 3012973
echo  - done.

echo ... COMPLETED (please remember to REBOOT windows, now)
pause
REM --- EOF
```

**"HideWindowsUpdates.vbs"** (Kudo [https://serverfault.com/a/341318](https://serverfault.com/a/341318/184613)):

```
'// Inspired by Colin Bowern: https://serverfault.com/a/341318
If Wscript.Arguments.Count < 1 Then
    WScript.Echo "Syntax: HideWindowsUpdates.vbs [KB1] [KB2] ..." & vbCRLF & _
        " - Example1: HideWindowsUpdates.vbs 3035583" & vbCRLF & _
        " - Example2: HideWindowsUpdates.vbs 3035583 3012973"
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

Dim objArgs
Set objArgs = Wscript.Arguments
Dim updateSession, updateSearcher
Set updateSession = CreateObject("Microsoft.Update.Session")
Set updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()

Wscript.Stdout.Write "Searching for pending updates..." 
Dim searchResult
Set searchResult = updateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0")

Dim update, kbArticleId, index, index2
WScript.Echo CStr(searchResult.Updates.Count) & " found."
For index = 0 To searchResult.Updates.Count - 1
    Set update = searchResult.Updates.Item(index)
    For index2 = 0 To update.KBArticleIDs.Count - 1
        kbArticleId = update.KBArticleIDs(index2)

        For Each hotfixId in objArgs
            If kbArticleId = hotfixId Then
                If update.IsHidden = False Then
                    WScript.Echo "Hiding update: " & update.Title
                    update.IsHidden = True
                Else
                    WScript.Echo "Already hiddn: " & update.Title
                End If          
            End If
        Next

    Next
Next
'// EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. In the meantime I was able to put together my script. Is imperfect, it may have bugs, but I ran it on my Windows 7 Pro x64 and it behaved as expected.

For anyone interested, please feel free to check it up here: https://github.com/dereius/WindowsUpdateHider